# SQLite Python printing data that consists of input string

Tags: python, sqlite

Is it possible to get all of the data that consists of the string that was input by the user?
For example, there's a movie title in database "HERO ACADEMY", so I enter academy and the output is "HERO ACADEMY".

```
pavadinimas = input("Title fragment: ")
sql = '''SELECT f.title
FROM film f
WHERE f.title LIKE ?'''

c.execute(sql, (pavadinimas,))
result = c.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Comment: You probably want `%` on either side of the search parameter.

Comment: I understand that, but how to make the program search for the users input? When I use this "WHERE f.title LIKE "%Academy%"; ''' " it works fine and gives me the correct output, but the problem is that I need to search for the users input from terminal

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution and updated my code to this:

```
pavadinimas = input("Title fragment: ")
c.execute("SELECT f.title FROM film f WHERE f.title LIKE ?", ('%'+pavadinimas+'%',))
result = c.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Added this line to the code:

```
c.execute("SELECT f.title FROM film f WHERE f.title LIKE ?", ('%'+pavadinimas+'%',))
```

My mistake was that I supplied a string as the second argument to c.execute, when I wanted to supply a single-element tuple containing the string.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to your own question - feel free to accept your own answer (with the checkmark), to show that the question is no longer open. By the way, your original example also passed a tuple `c.execute(sql, (pavadinimas,))`, so the main change here is that you're adding a `'%'` to the start and end of the query. Other than that, not a lot changed. In your solution, you define `sql` as a tuple as well, but end up not using it, as you're defining the query and parameter tuple anew in the call to `c.execute()`

Comment: Thank you for bringing it up, edited my answer :) I just have to wait for 2 days to accept it as the solution. Will do it, once it's ready.